# How to create jade-mixin with class name?

Tags: pug

I want to make jade mixin like this:

```
mixin use(value)
  svg(class=value role="img")
    use(xlink:href="#{svg}#value")
```

... to implement this mixin in document:

```
 ul
    li
      +use("icon-bubbles2")
```

... and compile in HTML:

```
<svg role="img" class="webicon-behance">
  <use xlink:href="images/svg-symbols.svg#bubbles"></use>
</svg>
```

But this mixin in not works and I have such HTML-code:

```
<svg role="img" class="value">
  <use xlink:href="images/svg-symbols.svg#value"></use>
</svg>
```

What's wrong in my mixin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 use(xlink:href="#{svg}#" + value)
```

ought to do it

```
use(xlink:href="#{svg}#{value}")
```

should work too, though I have not tried it and hence cannot be certain